# How to add polygon to a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vue2-google-maps

I am using Vue.js and vue2-google-maps to display a map and a polygon, but the function to show the polygon did not work. I am new to this framework.

I tried using the usual step from google maps tutorial using

```
map.data.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon(path)
```

but it did not work.

here is the script:

```
mounted() {
    this.addPolygon();
  },

  methods: {
    addPolygon(){
      var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: this.paths,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      console.log(this.poly);
      this.$refs.map.$mapObject.data.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([this.poly])});
    }
  }
```

how do I make this work?

Comment: Check your browser it's JavaScript-console to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based off of the library's [examples](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/tree/vue2/examples), it looks like you can add a simple polygon on your map like this:

```
<gmap-map
  :center="center"
  :zoom="13"
  style="width:100%;  height: 400px;" 
>
  <gmap-polygon :paths="paths"></gmap-polygon>
</gmap-map>
```

For guidance and demonstration you can check out this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-google-maps-b0cb4). Remember to add your own API key for the map to load correctly.

Hope this helps!